# Login not retaining user info

Tags: php, sql

I have created a basic user login function for my website, but it doesn't seem to be retaining the fact that the user is already logged in.
I have tried creating a function called 'logged_in' in my 'login_tools' file to check if the user is already logged in, and have tried to call this in the 'user_home' file but it isn't recognising it. I can't be sure then that it is actually working. Am I calling this the right way or in the right place? Or could it be a problem with the actual function itself?
I need to ensure that users can remain logged in until they log out manually themselves, as this underpins the next phase of my site, in which they can access database info that is specific to them.
Am posting those two files below, along with others for context.
Any advice appreciated on what I may be doing wrong.

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/head.php");
include("includes/search_box.php");
include("includes/left_sidebar.php");

?>

<html>
    <body>

    <h1>Login form</h1>
    <form action="login_process.php" method="POST">
    <p>
    Email address: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)){
        echo'<h1>Error!</h1>
        <p id="err_msg">There was a problem!<br>';
        foreach($errors as $msg){
            echo "- $msg<br>";
        }
        echo 'Please try again or <a href="registration.php">Register your profile</a></p>';
        }//if

    ?>
```

---

login_tools.php

```
<?php

function load_page($load_page = 'login.php'){
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    $url = rtrim($url,'/\\');
    $url.='/'.$load_page;
    header("Location:$url");
    exit();
}//load_page

function logged_in(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function validate_user($con, $user_email='', $user_password=''){

    $errors=array();


    if (empty($user_email)){
        $errors[]='Please enter your email address!';}//if
    else
    {$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($user_email));}//else


    if (empty($user_password)){
        $errors[]='Please enter your password!';}//if
    else
    {$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($user_password));}//else

    if(empty($errors)){
        $query_users = "select user_id, fName, sName from users where user_email='$email' and user_password=SHA1('$password')";
        $run_query_users=mysqli_query($con, $query_users);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query_users) == 1){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_users, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return array(true, $row);
        }//if
        else { $errors[] = 'Email and password have not been found';

        }//else
        }//if

    return array(false, $errors);

}

    //validate_user


?>
```

login_process.php

```
<?php

//Check login form has been submitted correctly

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    require("includes/db.php"); //Open db connection
    require("login_tools.php"); //Access login tools
    require("functions/functions.php");//

    //Verify if login has been successful and fetch user details
    list($verify, $details) = validate_user($db, $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);

    //Set session data for user details & load user homepage


    if ($verify){
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $details['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['fName'] = $details['fName'];
        $_SESSION['sName'] = $details['sName'];

        load_page('user_home.php');

    }//if
    else {$errors = $details;}

    //Close db connection
    mysqli_close($db);

    }//if



include ('login.php');

?>
```

user_home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/head.php");
include("includes/search_box.php");
include("includes/left_sidebar.php");

?>

<?php

session_start();

//Check if user is logged in already or proceed with logging them in

if (logged_in === true) {
    echo 'You are already logged in!<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
else {

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    require('login_tools.php');
    load_page();

    }//if

//Confirm user is logged on
echo"<h1>PROFILE PAGE</h1>
<p>You have successfully logged in, user number {$_SESSION['user_id']} {$_SESSION['fName']} {$_SESSION['sName']}</p>";

echo '<p>
<a href="user_itinerary.php">Your itinerary</a>
<a href="user_details.php">Your details</a>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</p>';

}//else

?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php

include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/head.php");
include("includes/search_box.php");
include("includes/left_sidebar.php");

//Allow access to session data

session_start();

//Redirect user to login page if they're not already logged in_array
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
require('login_tools.php'); load_page();
}

//Clear existing session variables
$_SESSION = array();

session_destroy();

echo "<p>You are now logged out.</p>
<p><a href=login.php>Login again here</a></p>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`session_start` should always be the first line of any php page, even before including all the external pages.

Make `session_start` the first line of every page.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. So it should be the first line of every php script? (Surely not in the HTML sections?)

Comment: @ThomasM
It should be the first line of every page where you need the user authentication to work. So suppose there's a simple static page with no intervention of queries, but you want this page to only be accessible upon authentication, then too the line `session_start` should be the first line.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this what's causing the problem do you think?

Comment: @ThomasM It is indeed.

Comment: On my 'user_home' page should session_start go even before the DOCTYPE HTML declaration at the very top then? Or between this and the start of the php script?

Comment: I forgot to add, by the way, that this message keeps coming up when I try to login as a user on the website:

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant logged_in - assumed 'logged_in' in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\user_home.php on line 17

Comment: @ThomasM
Yes, it should be before the DOCTYPE.
That error is coming because, `logged_in` is a function. In user_home.php, change `if (logged_in === true) {` to this :- `if (logged_in() === true) {`

Comment: Sorry mate, but neither of those are working. By changing that function with the () it now outputs this message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function logged_in() in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\user_home.php on line 18.

Also, when I move the 'session_start' before the DOCTYPE it just outputs 'session_start' at the top of my static html page.

Comment: @ThomasM I cannot help you with everything and spoon feed you. You should learn to debug your own code, the problems you've mentioned in your last comment are very simple to solve. I'd suggest you to invest some time debugging your code.